# VB.NET Syntax error in parameterized INSERT INTO Statement

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to insert data from VB.NET to MS Access but I am getting "Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement." from MessageBox.Show(ex.Message).

Is anyone free to take a look at my code and help me to fix my problem? Also, if you guys have better alternative way of coding this I will highly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class addNew
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection()
Dim sqlCom As New OleDbCommand()

Private Sub btnAddNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddNew.Click
    If txtFirstName.Text = "" Or txtLastName.Text = "" Or txtContact.Text = "" Or txtEmail.Text = "" Or comboMembershipType.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please complete the required fields.", "Authentication Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
        Try
            conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= " & Application.StartupPath & "\igcDatabase.accdb"
            sqlCom.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()

            sqlCom.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Members (Member First Name, Member Last Name, Contact Number, E-mail Address)" _
            & " VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @Contact, @Email)"

            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", txtFirstName.Text)
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastName", txtLastName.Text)
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("Contact", txtContact.Text)
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", txtEmail.Text)

            sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully added member!")
            conn.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Problem fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping your field names in [] e.g. [member first name].

You may be getting the syntax of the fields wrong.  Examining the rest of the exception might help reveal the syntax problem.

Comment: Thanks for help! My problem is fixed right immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I think the column names ware creating problem, Could you please check the column names please? whether it is typed correctly or not? I think there will not be space in between `Member First Name`. And I suggest you to use [`Parameters.Add()` instead for `Parameters.AddWithValue()`](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/); Following code will be a example for this:

```
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtFirstName.Text
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@LastName",OleDbType.VarChar).Value =  txtLastName.Text
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@Contact",OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtContact.Text
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@Email",OleDbType.VarChar).Value =txtEmail.Text
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick respond and suggestion. However, I am still getting the same error from Message.Show(ex.Message) after corrected the line to yours. If you don't mind, could you please go through my entire code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please check the column names please? whether it is typed correctly or not? I think there will not be space in between `Member First Name`

Comment: The column names is typed correctly. However, it's working after I changed the column names from the MS Access and VB.net to non-spacing. Thanks for your remind, really appreciate it.

Comment: There is no need for the @ in Parameters.Add function.

Comment: @nabuchodonossor , thanks for pointing it out. Appreciate it!